Need a clever add zero trick to finish a proof
Stuck on a proof with factorials
$$\left( \begin{array}   nn\\ k \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}   nn-k\\ j \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}   nn\\ j \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}   nn-j\\ k \end{array} \right)$$
I know you use the identity $n! = n(n-1)!$ to do these types of proofs. I think I ma most of the way there but what is throwing me off is I wind up with a $(n-k-j)!$ term.
Here is my attempt
$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{(n-k)!}{j!(n-k-j)!}=\left( \begin{array}   nn\\ j \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}   nn-j\\ k \end{array} \right)$$
Multiplying by $1$ and simplifying gets me to the following:
$$\frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}\frac{(n-j)!}{k!(n-k-j)!}=\left( \begin{array}   nn\\ j \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}   nn-j\\ k \end{array} \right)$$
So I need to change $(n-k-j)!$ to $(n-j-k)!$.
I assume I need to add zero but I do not see the trick and I need a hint.

Your first line appears to assume what you are trying to prove.  To avoid this appearance, start with one side or the other (do not write both).  Then apply a sequence of valid modifications to that side, writing what each modification gives you until ... you arrive at the same expression as on the other side.

Do you not see that $n-k-j = n-j-k$?  Addition is commutative...

@RobertIsrael It has been a while since I have worked on these types of problems and was fixated on the fact that subtraction is not commutative. I still need to knock the dust off this area of my brain. Question, why is subtraction not considered commutative if I can always just add the number of the opposite sign?


So I need to change $(n-k-j)! to (n-j-k)!$
I assume I need to add zero but I do not see the trick and I need a hint.

I think you're overthinking, as
$$
n-k-j
= n+(-k)+(-j)
= n+(-j)+(-k)
= n-j-k
$$
